# Laravel events not firing?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-events

I can't seem to get any of my `eloquent.saved` event handlers to run.

I tried this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher as DispatcherContract;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\EventServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $listen = [
        'eloquent.saved: \App\Models\Company' => [
            '\App\Models\Company@hasSaved',
        ],
    ];

}
```

And then added this method to `\App\Models\Company`:

```
public function hasSaved() {
    die("SAVED!!!");
}
```

But it doesn't run when I save a company.

I tried creating an observer:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Company;
use App\Observers\CompanyObserver;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    public function register()
    {
        Company::observe(CompanyObserver::class);
    }
}
```

But the events never fire:

```
<?php namespace App\Observers;

class CompanyObserver {

    public function saved() {
        die('saved');
    }

    public function saving() {
        die('saving');
    }
}
```

I tried using a listener class in `EventServiceProvider` instead:

```
protected $listen = [
    'eloquent.saved: \App\Models\Company' => [
        \App\Listeners\CompanySavedListener::class,
    ],
];
```

But that also never runs.

Lastly, I tried adding this to `EventServiceProvider`

```
public function boot(DispatcherContract $events)
{
    parent::boot($events);

    $events->listen('eloquent.*', function() {
        dump(func_get_args());
    });
}
```

And that does fire a bunch of random events, but it's just feeding me model instances -- I have no idea what events are actually firing.

So what's going on? I just want to know when my `Company` has saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's go for Observer way. The problem is that you used:

```
Company::observe(CompanyObserver::class);
```

in `register` method of `AppServiceProvider` and you should use it in `boot` method. When you move this line to `boot` method (of same class) it will work without a problem and when you save Company, code from `saved` method of `CompanyObserver` should be launched.